# AWS Beanstalk with Django: eb create complains about unknown config setting 'StaticFile'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a django app with Elasticbeanstalk, following this setup

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

and this

https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2017/05/23/tutorial-django-elastic-beanstalk/

At the first attempt, in the .ebextension/django.config, I have

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "my_django_path_name.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "my_django_path_name/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"
```

when calling `eb create`, it complains about

```
ERROR: ServiceError - Configuration validation exception: Invalid option specification (Namespace: 
'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python', OptionName: 'StaticFiles'): Unknown configuration setting.
```

So I took out the StaticFiles part, and eventually it becomes

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "my_django_path_name/wsgi.py"
```

and it STILL complains about the unknown OptionName: StaticFiles

Then I used the example in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-namespaces with minor tweaking

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: production.settings

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

yet it STILL complains about the same thing.

I don't know where the StaticFiles option name is being read. It doesn't exist in the .config file. Is it cached somewhere or something?

Comment: Are you sure this was the only place it was defined? Maybe there is a duplicate somewhere of the setting?

Comment: I only created one `.ebextension` folder ever. If bean stalk is indeed searching for that folder and all the `.config` files in it, this should be the only place

Comment: If you manually create your zip deployment and use EB console to create your env, does the error persist?

Comment: It seems like the new env is being created. Still, assuming this goes through, does that mean I have to zip my django app and upload everytime? I'd hope to have more of a programatic approach.

Comment: and deploy failed because of ` An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PreBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: EbExtension build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details`

Comment: `eb create` or `eb deploy` should suffice. Don't know why would they fail. Can run them with `--debug` or `--verbose` to get more info.

Comment: You are redeploying to same environment, or creating new one. In both cases it fails?

Comment: `eb create` and `eb deploy` returns the same msg, which is the one is the original question. adding verbosity doesn't help. I really think it's loading some old version of .config, i just don't know how to delete it

Comment: and redeploy and creating both fail going through eb cli

Comment: If you run `eb config` what do you get? Maybe you have some saved configurations?

Comment: [saved configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html) have higher precedence over `.ebextensions`.

Comment: I deleted the env with `eb terminate my-env-name` and attempt to `eb create my-env-name` again and same error. `eb config` returns nothing now that I don't have an existing env

Comment: maybe have to start from scratch, starting from `eb init`. Its possible something got totally mixed up.

Comment: okay I got it.... after turning debug on, i realized that eb cli is reading stuff from my git..... and I haven't committed my change to git yet..... wow

Comment: Nice. So basically what I said in the begining "Are sure this was the only place it was defined?"

Comment: If its working now, can I provide an answer based on the comments for future reference?

Comment: locally yes..... i thought i was going crazy..... did so many `find` and `grep` and whatnot.....

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, it was found that that the issue was caused by the fact `eb` was deploying an **old version from git**, rather then the local, corrected version of the application.

The solution was to **push the changes to git** so that new version get deployed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. As @Marcin mentioned above, `eb` CLI reads the files from `git`, so you need only to commit the changes to your local `git` repo before running `eb deploy`. No need to push to your remote repo.
2. As it seems that you are using the new `Amazon Linux 2` platform in EB, serving static files is removed from its features. So, you have to serve your static files externally through S3 bucket for an instance.

**Sources:**

- Amazon Linux 2 platforms limitations

  > Amazon Linux 2 platforms are missing some features compared to Amazon Linux AMI platforms (preceding Amazon Linux 2) : Serving static files and Custom platforms

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html

- staticfiles option is not supported

  > Configuring static files using the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles` namespace is only supported on Amazon Linux AMI Python platform versions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-namespaces

Comment: yea i get that I can't serve staticfile the way it used to. For now I'm not worrying about that. I need to the migration to run and it's still not running

Comment: Good. I have passed through all of this recently, please check my comment on your new question to check if I can help.